# What is the best way to transfer data [buffer] live from html 5 to c# socket server

Tags: html, sockets, websocket, server

I want to write live video call application in html5. I have written a web-socket server by c# for server side... 
Now i can get buffer live from camera in html5. But When i want to transfer this live buffer to server, and then push from server to client 2, its seem encode and decode byte array has low performance and live video will not appear...

this is my code for encoding byte array from server to client, please help me...

```
public byte[] EncodeMessageToSend(byte[] arr,
                                  bool bool_is_data) {
    byte[] response = null;
    byte[] bytesRaw = arr
    byte[] frame = new byte[10];

    int indexStartRawData = -1;
    int length = bytesRaw.Length;

    if (bool_is_data == false) {
        frame[0] = Convert.ToByte(129);
    } else {
        frame[0] = Convert.ToByte(130);
    }
    if (length <= 125) {
        frame[1] = Convert.ToByte(length);
        indexStartRawData = 2;
    } else if (length >= 126 && length <= 65535) {
        frame[1] = Convert.ToByte(126);
        frame[2] =  Convert.ToByte((length >> 8) & 255);
        frame[3] =  Convert.ToByte(length & 255);
        indexStartRawData = 4;
    } else {
        frame[1] = Convert.ToByte(127);
        frame[2] = Convert.ToByte((length >> 56) & 255);
        frame[3] = Convert.ToByte((length >> 48) & 255);
        frame[4] = Convert.ToByte((length >> 40) & 255);
        frame[5] = Convert.ToByte((length >> 32) & 255);
        frame[6] = Convert.ToByte((length >> 24) & 255);
        frame[7] = Convert.ToByte((length >> 16) & 255);
        frame[8] = Convert.ToByte((length >> 8) & 255);
        frame[9] = Convert.ToByte(length & 255);

        indexStartRawData = 10;
    }

    response = new byte[indexStartRawData + (length - 1)];
    int i = 0, reponseIdx = 0;

    //Add the frame bytes to the reponse
    for (int i = 0; i <= indexStartRawData - 1; i ++) {
        response[reponseIdx] = frame[i];
        reponseIdx += 1;
    }

    //Add the data bytes to the response
    for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i ++) {
        response[reponseIdx] = bytesRaw[i];
        reponseIdx += 1;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WebRTC technology.

You **can't** transmit audio and video over websocket.

You have to implement TURN server to relay audio/video streams and this is a bit complicated for hobby project.
You could look for existing solution instead.
And TURN server would be the last resort component in your solution because you could connect most clients in a p2p fashion by using yours or external STUN server.

Here are some usefull links to get started:

- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/
- https://github.com/vf1/turnserver - (I did not look into code but you
  could start with it)